# Large delete query seems to have frozen

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, delete

We ran a delete query on a database with 1.8bn rows. This delete would delete 1.2bn rows.

In hindsight, we would have broken up this query into 100m at a time but we are in a position where it has been running for 24 hours and the log file is at 2Tb which appears to be the maximum size allowed for a log file.

The database is in SIMPLE recovery mode.

Is there any saving this query? Or do we need to just restart the SQL Server and see what happens? Will the database be unusable? Is there anything we can do to kill this off as cleanly as possible?

Answer (score 14):

First of all, check the SQL errorlog to see if it actually hit a max size for the log. If it did, then the query has no hope of completing, it is probably already in a rollback state.

Even if it is, I always prefer to kill the spid manually (use `sp_who2` or `sp_WhoIsActive` to find the spid, then do a `kill 59` or whatever). You also can't check the rollback status unless you do an explicit KILL, [see this related thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/58583/cant-see-progress-of-rolling-back-spid-with-kill-with-statusonly).

Since this is a delete, and not an update or insert, you may be very lucky and find that it rolls back immediately. If not, it may take as long (or longer) to roll back as it did to get to this point.

To see the rollback status, use

```
kill 59 with statusonly
```

Unfortunately, I have found this frequently does not show anything useful, just a "0% complete". In that case, you'll have to use `sp_who2` and watch the IO and CPU to see if it is still doing something.

Regarding the reboot, this is a grave risk. If the spid is actively rolling back (CPU and IO are changing), then restarting SQL will only take the database offline entirely until the rollback is completely finished (hours and hours). *But*, if the CPU and IO are *not* moving, then it may in fact clear it right away. Either way, it is a risk.

One final option, if things are especially dire: **If you have a backup from just before the delete started (and there haven't been other updates to the db)**, then the fastest way to recover may be to simply drop the DB, restart SQL, and restore from backup.

If you can't drop the DB (or if you already restarted the instance and the sql errorlog is predicting a 24-hour recovery time), then shut down SQL services, delete the MDF and LDF files from disk, start up SQL, drop the (ghost) database, and restore from backup.

Obviously you'd only attempt that if this were a back-end processing database that users didn't interact with.

Comment: @Graeme - FYI - instead of trying to delete 1.2 billion rows, make a copy of the table structure, copy the rows you want to keep into the new table, then drop the old table.  If you add a new question asking how to do it, I can show you a very slick way that is much faster than deleting 1.2 billion rows.

Comment: My answer assumes the db is in SIMPLE recovery mode. If it is in FULL mode, you'll have to manage the huge tran log backups, too.

Answer (score 11):

DO NOT RESTART SQL SERVER.  This will only prolong your agony since recovery will take place, which will rollback or redo any transactions not completed, including your delete.

Killing the session that is running the delete will result in a rollback occurring, which will also take a long time to complete.

You want to look at the following query to see the state of the operation:

```
SELECT des.session_id 
    , des.host_name
    , des.login_name
    , der.command
    , der.estimated_completion_time
    , der.blocking_session_id
    , der.last_wait_type
    , der.percent_complete
    , der.start_time
    , der.status
    , der.wait_resource
    , der.wait_type
    , der.wait_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions des
    INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_requests der ON des.session_id = der.session_id
WHERE des.session_id <> @@SPID
    AND des.is_user_process = 1
ORDER BY des.session_id;
```

The `percent_complete` column, and those that rely on it, such as `estimated_completion_time`, are only populated for the following operations:

```
ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE
AUTO_SHRINK option with ALTER DATABASE
BACKUP DATABASE
DBCC CHECKDB
DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP
DBCC CHECKTABLE
DBCC INDEXDEFRAG
DBCC SHRINKDATABASE
DBCC SHRINKFILE
RECOVERY
RESTORE DATABASE
ROLLBACK
TDE ENCRYPTION
```

So you'll only see that column be meaningful if you've already cancelled the delete statement, and it is rolling back, or if you've already restarted the SQL Server and it is in recovery.

If the `blocking_session_id` column contains a number, that indicates that other session is blocking the delete operation.  If that session has been blocking the delete operation since it started you may be able to cancel the operation without any rollback needing to take place.